# Aunque con pretérito perfecto de subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo

Tengo dos preguntas:

1. Tengo dificultad en formular para mi misma condiciones de uso del pretérito perfecto de subjuntivo después de la conjunción *aunque*. He encontrado un montón de ejemplos con los otros tiempos gramaticales (presente de subjuntivo, pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo y pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo) pero los ejemplos con el pretérito perfecto no son tan numerosos. 
   Como ejemplo os dejo aquí algunas líneas (de unas canciones):

> a) Aunque hayan pruebas en tu camino no te dejes engañar...
>
> b) Tú siempre me tendrás atada a este amor, aunque hayas dicho
>   adiós...

2. ¿Si tuvieseis que traducir oraciones con el pretérito perfecto al inglés, usaríais „would + verbo“ o „would have + participio“? (p.ej. “would say” o “would have said” en la segunda frase)

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La frase "a" es incorrecta. Lo correcto sería "Aunque haya pruebas". Además, eso no es pretérito perfecto del subjuntivo. Pretérito perfecto sería: "Aunque haya habido" (uso unipersonal del verbo haber, igual que en el presente: hay pruebas)

Un par de reglas breves que te pueden ayudar:
https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/tiempos-subjuntivo/preterito-perfecto

Con respecto a la traducción de "b":
You will always have me tied/bound to this love, even though you've said goodbye.

"would say" no es una opción, porque "haya dicho" se refiere a una acción potencial de finalización reciente, es decir, que es reciente ahora, o que en caso de ocurrir, será reciente cuando ocurra otra.
La frase "b" es un tanto ambigua y puede entenderse así:
A pesar de que (recientemente) me has dicho adiós, seguiré atada a este amor.
Si en el futuro me dices adiós, a continuación de eso, seguiré atada a este amor.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @Wences, y perdón, mi culpa (falta de atención), por supuesto tienes razón, (a) no es pretérito perfecto del subjuntivo

Comment: ¡No hay problema! ¡Para servir!